# Adding significance levels manually to grouped ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a grouped ggplot using facet_wrap and added bars showing the level of significance using the "ggsignif" package. However, I would like to specify the level of significan myself. I know it is possible if you do it for an individual plot, but can it be done when you have "facet_wrap"ed your data?

In the description of the "stat_signif" function the "test" argument is described as following:

"the name of the statistical test that is applied to the values of the 2 columns (e.g. t.test, wilcox.test etc.). If you implement a custom test make sure that it returns a list that has an entry called p.value."

Is possible to add a column of p-values to the dataframe and use those somehow?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)

population <- rep(c(1:6),10)

A <- rnorm(60,5,1)
B <- rnorm(60,1,1)
C <- rnorm(60,2.5,1)

data <- tibble(population,A,B,C) %>% pivot_longer(2:4, "group")

data %>% ggplot(aes(group,value)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=group),width = 0.09, shape=21) +
  facet_wrap(~population) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("A", "C")),
              map_signif_level=T,
              test = "t.test",
              y_position = 9) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("B", "C")),
              map_signif_level=T,
              test = "t.test") +
  ylim(c(-1,10))
```

[image]

Comment: how about showing the p values in a table instead?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `ggpubr()` with and the `stat_compare_means()` function and I created the `my_comparisons` lists

```
library(ggpubr)


my_comparisons <- list( c("B", "C"), c("A", "C"))

data %>% ggplot(aes(group,value)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=group),width = 0.09, shape=21) +
  facet_wrap(~population)+
     stat_compare_means(mapping=aes(label=..p.adj..), 
                        comparisons=my_comparisons, 
                         method = "t.test")
```

[image]

Comment: But then you display the p-values generated with the stat_compare_means function. I would like to add levels of significance that I calculate outside the ggplot.